# Subbasic and basic open sets of the weak-* topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. We define the weak-$^*$ topology on $X^*$ to be the initial topology generated by all linear functionals $ev_x: X^*\rightarrow F$ defined by
$$
f\mapsto f(x).
$$
Here is my professor's description about the subbasic open sets and basic open sets with respect to the weak-$^*$ topology:

[image]

My question is, why do we need $g(y)$ here? My description of the subbasic open set is
$$
V_{y,c,\delta} = \{f\in X^{*}: |f(y)-c| < \delta\},
$$
which is preimage of the open set $B(c,\delta)$ under the evaluation map $ev_y$. Could someone point out my mistake in reasoning?

Thank you!

**Update:** My instructor confirmed that the two kinds of basic open sets generate the same topology.

Comment: The definitions are not the same. Let $e_x(f)=f(x), \rho_x(f)=|f(x)|$. Your definition is the weakest topology on $X^*$ in the category of topological spaces for which $\{e_x\colon x\in X\}$
 are continuous functions. It's not a topology of a topological vector space. The professor's definition is for the weakest topology that makes $X^*$
 into a topological vector space and for which the seminorms $\{\rho_x\colon x
\in X\}$ are continuous.

Comment: @ChadK Thank you! But I read the lecture notes again and I think my professor and I both described the subbasic/basic open sets of the weak-$^*$ topology. I have updated my post to be clearer. Could you take a look again and help point out my mistake?

Comment: You're right, it's the same topology.  Starting with $V_{y,g,\delta}$, let $c=g(y)$ and then $V_{y,g,\delta}=V_{y,c,\delta}$.  Conversely, starting with $V_{y,c,\delta}$, if $y=0$ then $V_{y,c,\delta}=X^*$ for $|c|<\delta$ or $V_{y,c,\delta}=\emptyset$ for $|c|\ge\delta$.  If $y\ne 0$ there is $g\in X^*$ such that $g(y)=c$ and then $V_{y,c,\delta}=V_{y,g,\delta}$.

Comment: The reason I got confused is because in TVSs it's usual to work with a neighborhood subbase at zero $U_{y,\delta}=\{f\in X^{*}\colon |f(y)| < \delta\}$ and then the other subbase neighborhoods are translates $g+U_{y,\delta}$ for $g\in X^*$.  That's the background for your professor's definition.

Comment: Thank you!@ChadK Just to make sure, do you mean that both my professor's and my description of subbasic and basic open sets are correct, but in different forms? And he writes that way because of some convention reason.